# How do I collapse child categories as I edit a post in the Wordpress dashboard

Tags: wordpress, categories

I have lots of child categories in WordPress and don't need all of them all the time. I would like to collapse child categories as I edit posts. How do I do this? Any plugins that I found seem to be years old.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`wp_list_categories` which is probably what you're looking for. [See the WordPress codex](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_list_categories/) for more information.

```
wp_list_categories(array(
    'style' => 'none',
    'orderby' => 'name',
    'show_count' => true,
    'hierarchical' => true,
    'depth' => 1
));
```